# Ensure libraries in /usr/lib{64} are found before those defined in /etc/ld.so.conf

Tags: linux, fedora-15, shared-libraries, oracle-11g

I am running Fedora 15 x86_64 and have the Oracle 11 client installed, and have an `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf` file configured so I can automatically pick-up the client shared object file.  However Oracle also comes with other shared objects that I **don't** want to override the system libraries (libexpat in this case).

As there is no definition for `/usr/lib64` in the `ld.so.conf` files, how do I make it the first directory that `ld.so` searches for shared objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can add that definition in to `/etc/ld.so.conf` or to a file of your own name (I THINK it will pick them up alphabetically, you'll need to experiment) so `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/a.conf` should be picked up first. Make sure you run `/sbin/ldconfig` after altering or adding the previous files.

As a last resort, you can use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.
There is some decent information [here](http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/notes/rpath.html) and [here](http://prefetch.net/articles/linkers.badldlibrary.html) about why NOT to use that variable if you can help it.